# Sum up true false in pandas df using plotly dash for visualization

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

I have the following CSV Data:

```
    id,expNumber,attempt,finished,successful,
    1,1,1,true,false,
    1,1,2,false,false,
    1,1,3,true,true,
    1,2,1,false,false,
    1,2,2,true,false,
    1,2,3,true,true,
    1,4,1,false,false,
    1,4,2,false,false,
```

I want to use Plotly Dash and DashTable for visualization of the data. The goal is to get a chart which shows me the sum of true/false for a specific task or for all task, if nothing choosed and for successful/finished or both of it, if nothing choosed.

I tried with the following code:

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from dash import dash_table
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("..\data.csv")

df.set_index('id', inplace=True, drop=False)

app = dash.Dash(__name__, prevent_initial_callbacks=True)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dash_table.DataTable(
        id='datatable-interactivity',
        columns=[
            {"name": "ExperimentID", "id": "expNumber", "deletable": False, "selectable": True, "type": 'numeric'},
            {"name": "id", "id": "id", "deletable": False, "selectable": True, "type": 'numeric'},
            {"name": "Attempt", "id": "attempt", "deletable": False, "selectable": True, "type": 'numeric'},
            {"name": "Finished", "id": "finished", "deletable": False, "selectable": True, "type": 'text'},
            {"name": "Successful", "id": "successful", "deletable": False, "selectable": True, "type": 'text'},
        ],
        data=df.to_dict('records'),
        editable=False,
        filter_action="native",('none')
        sort_action="native",not ('none')
        sort_mode="single",
        column_selectable="multi",
        row_selectable="multi",
        row_deletable=False,
        selected_columns=[],
        selected_rows=[],
        page_action="native",
        page_current=0,
        page_size=10,
        style_cell={                
            'minWidth': 95, 'maxWidth': 95, 'width': 95
        }
    ),

    html.Br(),
    html.Br(),
    html.Div(id='bar-container'),
    html.Div(id='choromap-container')

])

# Create bar chart
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='bar-container', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='datatable-interactivity', component_property="derived_virtual_data"),
     Input(component_id='datatable-interactivity', component_property='derived_virtual_selected_rows'),
     Input(component_id='datatable-interactivity', component_property='derived_virtual_selected_row_ids'),
     Input(component_id='datatable-interactivity', component_property='selected_rows'),
     Input(component_id='datatable-interactivity', component_property='derived_virtual_indices'),
     Input(component_id='datatable-interactivity', component_property='derived_virtual_row_ids'),
     Input(component_id='datatable-interactivity', component_property='active_cell'),
     Input(component_id='datatable-interactivity', component_property='selected_cells')]
)
def update_bar(all_rows_data, slctd_row_indices, slct_rows_names, slctd_rows,
               order_of_rows_indices, order_of_rows_names, actv_cell, slctd_cell):

    dff = pd.DataFrame(all_rows_data)

    if "expNumber" in dff:
        return [
            dcc.Graph(id='bar-chart',
                      figure=px.bar(
                          data_frame=dff,
                          x="finished",
                          y="expNumber",
                          labels={"": ""}
                      ).update_layout(showlegend=False, xaxis={'categoryorder': 'total ascending'})
                      .update_traces(hovertemplate="<b>%{y}%</b><extra></extra>")
                      )

        ]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

The Problem is, I don't get a real count of true/false. The chart is just displaying the sum of taskIds where finished is true.

So i tried to set up the y-axis of the chart with "y=df.groupby(['expNumber'])[['successful']].sum(),"

When I execute this code, with this y parameter I get an error "KeyError: 0".

Do you have an idea where I did a mistake?

I know that currently I do not take into account any selection of the task or attribute. My first concern is to find out if I can represent it using the expNumber and Successful example.

Here is a little mockup about what I expect:

[image: Mockup]

There should also be the possibility to select only one attribute or only one task. Is it possible to implement something like this with Plotly?

Comment: Why do you use all these inputs?

Comment: I wasn't sure if I need these inputs to specify which colums/rows are selected by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understood your desired output:

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from dash import dash_table
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

df.set_index('id', inplace=True, drop=False)

app = dash.Dash(__name__, prevent_initial_callbacks=True)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dash_table.DataTable(
        id='datatable-interactivity',
        columns=[
            {"name": "ExperimentID", "id": "expNumber", "deletable": False, "selectable": True, "type": 'numeric'},
            {"name": "id", "id": "id", "deletable": False, "selectable": True, "type": 'numeric'},
            {"name": "Attempt", "id": "attempt", "deletable": False, "selectable": True, "type": 'numeric'},
            {"name": "Finished", "id": "finished", "deletable": False, "selectable": True, "type": 'text'},
            {"name": "Successful", "id": "successful", "deletable": False, "selectable": True, "type": 'text'},
        ],
        data=df.to_dict('records'),
        editable=False,
        filter_action="native",
        sort_action="native",
        sort_mode="single",
        column_selectable="multi",
        row_selectable="multi",
        row_deletable=False,
        selected_columns=[],
        selected_rows=[],
        page_action="native",
        page_current=0,
        page_size=10,
        style_cell={                
            'minWidth': 95, 'maxWidth': 95, 'width': 95
        }
    ),

    html.Br(),
    html.Br(),
    html.Div(id='bar-container'),
    html.Div(id='choromap-container')

])

# Create bar chart
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='bar-container', component_property='children'),
    [
     Input(component_id='datatable-interactivity', component_property='selected_rows'),
     Input(component_id='datatable-interactivity', component_property='selected_columns')]
)
def update_bar(slctd_rows,slctd_cols):
    if slctd_cols != []:
        
        if slctd_rows != []:
            dff = df.iloc[slctd_rows].copy()
        else:
            dff= df.copy()
            
        graph =  [
                dcc.Graph(id='bar-chart',
                          figure=px.histogram(
                              data_frame=dff,
                              x=slctd_cols[-1],
                                        ).update_layout(
                              barmode='group',showlegend=False, xaxis={'categoryorder': 'total ascending'})
                          )

            ]
        return graph

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This works for me but I have one (little?) problem with it. When I don't choose the "ExperimentID" checkbox, it works well. But if I choose the ExperimentID check box, the output isn't really useful. I tried to do something like "x=[slctd_cols[-1], dff['expNumber']]" but it drops the Error "ValueError: Plotly Express cannot process wide-form data with columns of different type." Do you have an idea how I can solve this problem and also display the values grouped by ExperimentID ?

Comment: @ Jukebox what should happen when the user clicks ExperimentID check box because it is not clear in the question?

Comment: I added one of my mockups. Is it possible to build something like this with plotly or is it the wrong tool for my usecase?

Comment: @JukeboxHero, you replied to my question with another question :) what should happen when the user clicks ExperimentID check box?

Comment: It is not possible to achieve that without Dash.

Comment: Sorry, I though the mockup explains what should happen. But anyway.. Thank you!